# Stuck in a slide

Tags: javascript, slideshow, slide

I can't get my slides running do I miss calling the right function in the right way(probably a stupid question) :)

```
function runSlideshow() {
  let intervalId = setInterval(function () {
    //Alla bilderna
    let slideshowImages = document.querySelectorAll("#slideshow img");
    //Sista bilden
    let lastImage = slideshowImages[slideshowImages.length - 1];
    console.log("Tona ut bilden", lastImage);
    let opacity = 1;
    let fadeOutId = setInterval(function () {
      lastImage.style.opacity = opacity;
      if (opacity > 0) {
        opacity -= 0.01;
      } else {
        clearInterval(fadeOutId);
        opacity = 1;
      }
    }, 1000 / 60);
  }, 5000);
  return intervalId;

  function FadeOut(moveImage) {
    image.style;
  }
}
runSlideshow();
runFadeout();
runMoveImage();

function moveImage(image) {
  image.remove();
  slideshow.prepend(image);
}
```

Comment: You currently have no functions called `runFadeOut` or `runMoveImage`. Also, it would help if you provided some HTML.

Comment: Please provide more context. HTML and a description of what you're trying to do exactly will be useful.